# Maximise Remote IE Browser

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, virtual-machine, microsoft-test-manager

I have been running tests on a remote XP client for some time now. My tests are written in C# using Selenium's WebDriver (Version 2.20.0) and the IE Driver (Version 2.20.1.0) with these tests being remotely run on a XP Client managed by Microsoft's Lab Management.

My issue is that upon creating an IE Browser I am unable to maximise it on the Client through Selenium calls. Instead I am trying manually with the following:

```
_driver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
```

Along with *WorkingArea* I have also tried *Bounds*, but to no avail as both increase the window size but do not position it to the center correctly. I assume this is because a VM has no monitor and thus no way of knowing the actual resolution? I want to just call something that will 'maximise' the window to the full screen without specifying the size.

Comment: What's wrong with `_driver.Manage().Window.Maximise();`? Did it not do anything at all?

Comment: Does not appear to be a method within my driver. A versioning issue I assume? I wanted to avoid upgrading to a newer Selenium.WebDriver if possible, but I can if it's necessary, just want to confirm it solves my issue.

Comment: From the looks of things, .`Maximise()` was introduced in v2.21.

Comment: Why avoid upgrading to a newer version? Bugs and enhancements are fixed all the time, and it's highly recommended that you run with the latest version.

Comment: @JimEvans I agree completely, however we have a deploy coming up soon and wanted to avoid introducing anything new to avoid complications. Just wanted to know if I have other options. I believe I will push for an upgrade anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running the tests remotely and you need window to be re sized at client side. I would suggest you do it via JavaScript Injection.

The best thing...it executes on client side, so no worries. In JavaScript I moved the window to (0,0) axis first and then i maximized the window screen to Maximum available (Width, Height).

Here is code...in C#

```
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

    IJavaScriptExecutor JSDriver = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;

    JSDriver.ExecuteScript("window.moveTo(0, 0)");
    JSDriver.ExecuteScript("window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);");
```

I hope this helps...All the best

Comment: Client side makes much more sense to me now, thanks! Though I think I will be upgrading to the newest WebDriver shortly as it's really something I should do!

Comment: Glad to know...it helped you. Yep that's something mandatory step, being active development/bug fixes happening around you should always refer to latest WebDriver versions.

Comment: Was able to convince my team lead that the upgrade was necessary and the upgrade allowed me to use Maximize with no issue.